# Create new column in dataframe passing existing column to an SQL function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which contains NAME as a column.

I have a DB statement which returns the FIRST_NAME when NAME is passed.

I am writing a python script something like below:

```
def fname(row):
 cursor.execute(select case when df['name'] = fname then fname else blank end as fname from dual;)
 return cursor.fetchone()[]

df[fname]=df.apply(fname)
```

It seems to throw "expects the first argument to be string or unicode"

How do I pass name value one by one to the function above and store it in a new column in the same dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify axis=1, by default the axis =0 which mean it reads the indexes.

```
df[name]=df.apply(fname, axis=1)
```

> axis{0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
>
> Axis along which the function is applied:
>
> 0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column.
>   1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row.

For more details , refer the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: can you provide a sample data in the question ? It would be easier to help then

Answer (score 0):

found the issue. since i am passing the dataframe as row in the function, i have to refer the dataframe as row inside this function

def fname(row):
 cursor.execute(select case when row['name'] = fname then fname else blank end as fname from dual;)
 return cursor.fetchone()[]

df[fname]=df.apply(fname)